# My program get crazy

Tags: c

I tried to do a program that random 10000 numbers between 0-6 and check how much times every number get ruffle. It's get crazy and print lot's of things. please help me thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 10000
#define NUM_OF_FACES 6

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arrCube[ARR_SIZE];
    int i=0,counter=0,j=0;
    for(i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        arrCube[i] = rand() % NUM_OF_FACES;
    }   
    for(i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++)
    {
        counter=0;
        for(j=i+1;j<ARR_SIZE -1;j++)
        {
            if (arrCube[i]==arrCube[j])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d times %d showed up\n",counter,arrCube[i]);
    }    

    return (0);
}
```

Another thing: I know that I can do this program with another array instead the nested loop. someone know?

Comment: First of all, you could just check against fixed values (0-6) instead of nesting loops. Second, please write a meaningful title.

Comment: Please think before you write code. What's the nested loop meant to compute?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have an extra array that calculate the frequencies:

```
int main() 
{ 
  srand(time(NULL));
  int arrCube[ARR_SIZE];
  int freqs[NUM_OF_FACES] = {0}; 
  int i=0,counter=0,j=0, val;
  for(i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
  { 
      val = rand() % NUM_OF_FACES; 
      arrCube[i] = val;
      ++freqs[val];
  } 

  for(i =0 ; i < NUM_OF_FACES; i++)
      printf("%d showed up %d times\n",i,freqs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another code version, that should solve your problem. I tried to stay close to your original version. In the old version you checked for every random number as many times as it appeared in your array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 10000
#define NUM_OF_FACES 6

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arrCube[ARR_SIZE];
    int i=0,counter=0,j=0,all=0;
    for(i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        arrCube[i] = rand() % NUM_OF_FACES;
    }
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_FACES;i++)
    {
       counter = 0;
       for(j=0;j<ARR_SIZE;j++)
       {
          if (i==arrCube[j])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
      printf("%d times %d showed up\n",counter,i);
      all=all+counter;
    }
    printf("total %d\n",all);

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nested loops are indeed not the best solution: you're iterating many more times than necessary, and that's also resulting in substantially more output than you need: 10,000 lines of it, in fact. Crazy!

Replace the outer loop over the array with a loop over 0→`NUM_OF_FACES`.

Furthermore, you could collapse the nested loops into just one by keeping an array `int frequency[NUM_OF_FACES] = {}` then incrementing `frequency[arrCube[i]]` for each `i` in 0→`ARR_SIZE`.

Then you just need a new, final loop over `frequency` to print the six lines of results

Answer (score 1):

Replace your nested loops with a simple [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort):

```
int bucket[NUM_OF_FACES] = { 0 };

/* Put the "ruffles" in the right bucket */
for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) 
{
    bucket[arrCube[i]]++;
}

/* Print the result */
for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) 
{
    printf("%d times %d showed up\n", bucket[i], i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, it 'get's crazy' simply because of the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++)
{
    counter=0;
    ...
    printf("%d times %d showed up\n",counter,arrCube[i]);
}
```

printf is repeated ARR_SIZE times

the following code would most likely be what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TESTS 10000
#define NUM_OF_FACES 6

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arrCube[NUM_FACES];
    int i;

    /* init every entry to 0 */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FACES; i++)
    {
        arrCube[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < TESTS; i++)
    {
        arrCube[ rand() % NUM_OF_FACES ]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FACES; i++)
    {
        printf("the number %d showed up %d times\n", i, arrCube[i]);
    }
}
```